# Cannot retrieve data from javascript json object created in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, gson

I have a servlet where it returns a string like `[["one","two"],["one","two"]]`, which is an array representation.

This was sent to the front end using the Gson library's `toJson()` method as a String. It sends this String array along with some other attributes in JSON format and then I'm using the `toJson()` method to send it to front end.

In the Ajax response handling, I'm doing a `$.parseJSON()` on the object and retrieving the values. *(It works fine and I was able to retrieve that array string.)*

Now in JavaScript I need to create another JSON object with some other values along with this string array and send it to another JavaScript method. But in that method I cannot retrieve the values. My motive is to extract this array string as an array and iterate it.

**Following is what I do in JavaScript to send to JavaScript method:**

```
var streamId = stream + CONSTANTS.colon + streamVersion;
var eventsData = {};
var jsonData = [];

eventsData ["source"] = streamId;
eventsData ["data"] = eventsArray;
jsonData.push(eventsData);
onSuccessFunction(jsonData);
```

In `onSuccessFunction` I tried to get `jsonData.data`, but it says undefined.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You don't create a variable called eventsArray anywhere. Perhaps your code snippet isn't broad enough?

Comment: Andrew that whole code is inside a method which takes a parameter as eventsArray. Sorry i did not put the wrapped function.

Comment: It's important to see how that function is being called.

Comment: this what i get for constructed jsonData. [Object { source="testStream", data="[["dsfsa","asdasd","sdfsf","sdfs"]]"}] ..